# How to extract only 3 eigen vectors of an nxn image in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, linear-algebra

I am trying to convert a RGB image to Grayscale using the following [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Novel-PCA-based-color-to-gray-image-conversion-Seo-Kim/7c23493d4cbe69c6eed697f6394d0f31c660e6ca/pdf).

The main algorithm using in the paper is this:
[Novel PCA based algorithm to convert images to grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTJIR.png)

However, when I am trying to extract eigen vectors from the image I am getting 500 eigen values, instead of 3 as required. As far as I know, a NxN matrix usually gives N Eigen vectors, but I am not really sure what I should be doing here to get only 3 Eigen vectors.

Any help as to what I should do? Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def pca_rgb2gray(img):
    """
    NOVEL PCA-BASED COLOR-TO-GRAY IMAGE CONVERSION
    Authors:
    -Ja-Won Seo
    -Seong Dae Kim
    2013 IEEE International Conference on Image Processing
    """
    I_re = cv2.resize(img, (500,500))
    Iycc = cv2.cvtColor(I_re, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
    Izycc = Iycc - Iycc.mean()
    eigvals = []
    eigvecs = []
    final_im = []
    for i in range(3):
        res = np.linalg.eig(Izycc[:,:,i])
        eigvals.append(res[0])
        eigvecs.append(res[1])
    eignorm = np.linalg.norm(eigvals)
    for i in range(3):
        eigvals[i]/=eignorm
        eigvecs[i]/=np.linalg.norm(eigvecs[i])
        temp = eigvals[i] * np.dot(eigvecs[i], Izycc[:,:,i])
        final_im.append(temp)
    final_im = final_im[0] + final_im[1] + final_im[2]
    return final_im
if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = cv2.imread('image.png')
    gray = pca_rgb2gray(img)
```

Comment: You compute eigenvalues on an `3xN` matrix, where 3 is the number of channels in BGR, and N is the total number of pixels... So you get 3 eigenvalues. Check Sect. 2.2 in your paper

Comment: But eigen values and vectors are defined only for square matrices.

Comment: Actually  [you can](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207991/eigenvalues-of-a-rectangular-matrix). But you need to compute [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

Comment: @Miki I see, thanks. Also if A is my 3xN matrix, will computing Eigenvectors and values of AA' be the same as calculating the PCA?

Comment: For non-square matrices, you need to calculate SVD of the matrix and it gives you singular values instead of eigen-values. Singular values of A are square roots of eigen values of A'A. In fact finding eigen-values are not necessarily a PCA calculation. PCA is a statistical method of finding eignevalues of the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Background

When Seo and Kim ask for `lambda_i, v_i <- PCA(Iycc)`, for `i = 1, 2, 3`, they want:

```
from numpy.linalg import eig
lambdas, vs = eig(np.dot(Izycc, Izycc.T))
```

for a 3×N array `Izycc`. That is, they want the three eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the 3×3 covariance matrix of `Izycc`, the 3×N array (for you, N = 500*500).

However, you almost never want to compute the covariance matrix, then find its eigendecomposition, because of numerical instability. There is a much better way to get the same `lambdas, vs`, using the singular value decomposition (SVD) of `Izycc` directly (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3871/81266)). The code below shows you how to do this.

## Just show me the code

First download http://cadik.posvete.cz/color_to_gray_evaluation/img/155_5572_jpg/155_5572_jpg.jpg and save it as `peppers.jpg`.

[image: Peppers test image via Cadik]

Then, run the following:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from numpy.linalg import svd, norm

# Read input image
Ibgr = cv2.imread('peppers.jpg')

# Convert to YCrCb
Iycc = cv2.cvtColor(Ibgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)

# Reshape the H by W by 3 array to a 3 by N array (N = W * H)
Izycc = Iycc.reshape([-1, 3]).T

# Remove mean along Y, Cr, and Cb *separately*!
Izycc = Izycc - Izycc.mean(1)[:, np.newaxis]

# Make sure we're dealing with zero-mean data here: the mean for Y, Cr, and Cb
# should separately be zero. Recall: Izycc is 3 by N array.
assert(np.allclose(np.mean(Izycc, 1), 0.0))

# Compute data array's SVD. Ignore the 3rd return value: unimportant.
(U, S) = svd(Izycc, full_matrices=False)[:2]

# Square the data's singular vectors to get the eigenvalues. Then, normalize
# the three eigenvalues to unit norm and finally, make a diagonal matrix out of
# them. N.B.: the scaling factor of `norm(S**2)` is, I believe, arbitrary: the
# rest of the algorithm doesn't really care if/how the eigenvalues are scaled,
# since we will rescale the grayscale values to [0, 255] anyway.
eigvals = np.diag(S**2 / norm(S**2))

# Eigenvectors are just the left-singular vectors.
eigvecs = U;

# Project the YCrCb data onto the principal components and reshape to W by H
# array.
Igray = np.dot(eigvecs.T, np.dot(eigvals, Izycc)).sum(0).reshape(Iycc.shape[:2])

# Rescale Igray to [0, 255]. This is a fancy way to do this.
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
Igray = np.floor((interp1d([Igray.min(), Igray.max()],
                            [0.0, 256.0 - 1e-4]))(Igray))

# Make sure we don't accidentally produce a photographic negative (flip image
# intensities). N.B.: `norm` is often expensive; in real life, try to see if
# there's a more efficient way to do this.
if norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - Igray) > norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - (255.0 - Igray)):
    Igray = 255 - Igray

# Display result
if True:
    import pylab
    pylab.ion()
    pylab.imshow(Igray, cmap='gray')

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('peppers-gray.png', Igray.astype(np.uint8))
```

This produces the following grayscale image, which seems to match the result in Figure 4 of the paper (though see caveat at the bottom of this answer!):

[image: Grayscale peppers]

## Errors in your implementation

`Izycc = Iycc - Iycc.mean()` **WRONG.** `Iycc.mean()` flattens the image and computes the mean. You want `Izycc` such that the Y channel, Cr channel, *and* Cb channel all have zero-mean. You could do this in a `for dim in range(3)`-loop, but I did it above with array broadcasting. I also have an assert above to make sure this condition holds. The trick where you get the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix from the SVD of the data array *requires* zero-mean Y/Cr/Cb channels.

`np.linalg.eig(Izycc[:,:,i])` **WRONG.** The contribution of this paper is to use principal components to convert color to grayscale. This means you have to combine the colors. The processing you were doing above was on a channel-by-channel basis—no combination of colors. Moreover, it was totally wrong to decompose the 500×500 array: the width/height of the array don’t matter, only pixels. For this reason, I reshape the three channels of the input into 3×whatever and operate on that matrix. Make sure you understand what’s happening after BGR-to-YCrCb conversion and before the SVD.

Not so much an error but a caution: when calling [`numpy.linalg.svd`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html), the `full_matrices=False` keyword is important: this makes the “economy-size” SVD, calculating just three left/right singular vectors and just three singular values. The full-sized SVD will attempt to make an N×N array of right-singular vectors: with N = 114270 pixels (293 by 390 image), an N×N array of `float64` will be `N ** 2 * 8 / 1024 ** 3` or 97 gigabytes.

## Final note

The magic of this algorithm is really in a single line from my code:

```
Igray = np.dot(eigvecs.T, np.dot(eigvals, Izycc)).sum(0) # .reshape...
```

This is where The Math is thickest, so let’s break it down.

- `Izycc` is a 3×N array whose rows are zero-mean;
- `eigvals` is a 3×3 diagonal array containing the **eigenvalues** of the covariance matrix `dot(Izycc, Izycc.T)` (as mentioned above, computed via a shortcut, using SVD of `Izycc`),
- `eigvecs` is a 3×3 orthonormal matrix whose columns are the **eigenvectors** corresponding to those eigenvalues of that covariance.

Because these are Numpy `array`s and not `matrix`es, we have to use `dot(x,y)` for matrix-matrix-multiplication, and then we use `sum`, and both of these obscure the linear algebra. You can check for yourself but the above calculation (before the `.reshape()` call) is equivalent to

```
np.ones([1, 3]) · eigvecs.T · eigvals · Izycc = dot([[-0.79463857, -0.18382267,  0.11589724]], Izycc)
```

where `·` is true matrix-matrix-multiplication, and the `sum` is replaced by pre-multiplying by a row-vector of ones. Those three numbers,

1. -0.79463857 multiplying each pixels’s Y-channel (luma),
2. -0.18382267 multiplying Cr (red-difference), and
3. 0.11589724 multiplying Cb (blue-difference),

specify the “perfect” weighted average, for this particular image: each pixel’s Y/Cr/Cb channels are being aligned with the image’s covariance matrix and summed. Numerically speaking, each pixel’s Y-value is slightly attenuated, its Cr-value is significantly attenuated, and its Cb-value is even more attenuated but with an opposite sign—this makes sense, we expect the luma to be most informative for a grayscale so its contribution is the highest.

## Minor caveat

I’m not really sure where OpenCV’s RGB to YCrCb conversion comes from. The documentation for [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor), specifically the section on RGB ↔︎ YCrCb JPEG doesn’t seem to correspond to any of the transforms specified on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion). When I use, say, the [Colorspace Transformations](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28790) Matlab package to just do the RGB to YCrCb conversion (which cites the Wikipedia entry), I get a nicer grayscale image which appears to be more similar to the paper’s Figure 4:

[image: Matlab color transformation, Python code]

I’m totally out of my depth when it comes to these color transformations—if someone can explain how to get Wikipedia or Matlab’s Colorspace Transformations equivalents in Python/OpenCV, that’d be very kind. Nonetheless, this caveat is about preparing the data. After you make `Izycc`, the 3×N zero-mean data array, the above code fully-specifies the remaining processing.

Comment: According to the document, `cv2.cvtColor` is simply a linear combination, which shouldn't have an effect on the result of PCA, but removing that line does give me a different (and worse) image. Do you have any idea about what's happening there?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer by Ahmed unfortunately has the PCA math wrong, leading to the a result quite different to the manuscript. Here are the images screen captured from the manuscript. [image: original images in manuscript]

The mean centring and SVD should be done along the other dimension, with the channels treated as the different samples. The mean centring is aimed at getting an average pixel response of zero, not an average channel response of zero.

The linked algorithm also clearly states that the projection of the PCA model involves multiplication of the image by the scores first and this product by the eigenvalues, not the other way round as in the other answer.

For further info on the math see my [PCA math answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404731/eigenvalues-as-weighting-factors-for-projection-results-on-corresponding-eigenve/405999#405999)

The difference in the code can be seen in the outputs. Since the manuscript did not provide an example output (that I found) there may be subtle differences between the results as the manuscript ones are captured screenshots.

For comparison, the downloaded colour file, which is a little more contrasted than the screenshot, so one would expect the same from the output greyscale.
[image: downloaded colour file]

First the result from Ahmed's code:
[image: Ahmeds result]

Then the result from the updated code:
[image: new result]

The corrected code (based on Ahmed's for ease of comparison) is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from numpy.linalg import svd, norm

# Read input image
Ibgr = cv2.imread('path/peppers.jpg')
#Convert to YCrCb
Iycc = cv2.cvtColor(Ibgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)

# Reshape the H by W by 3 array to a 3 by N array (N = W * H)
Izycc = Iycc.reshape([-1, 3]).T

# Remove mean along Y, Cr, and Cb *separately*!
Izycc = Izycc - Izycc.mean(0)  #(1)[:, np.newaxis]
# Mean across channels is required (separate means for each channel is not a 
# mathematically sensible idea) - each pixel's variation should centre around 0

# Make sure we're dealing with zero-mean data here: the mean for Y, Cr, and Cb
# should separately be zero. Recall: Izycc is 3 by N array. 
# Original assertion was based on a false presmise. Mean value for each pixel should be 0
assert(np.allclose(np.mean(Izycc, 0), 0.0))

# Compute data array's SVD. Ignore the 3rd return value: unimportant in this context. 
(U, S, L) = svd(Izycc, full_matrices=False)

# Square the data's singular vectors to get the eigenvalues. Then, normalize
# the three eigenvalues to unit norm and finally, make a diagonal matrix out of
# them. 
eigvals = np.diag(S**2 / norm(S**2))

# Eigenvectors are just the right-singular vectors.
eigvecs = U;

# Project the YCrCb data onto the principal components and reshape to W by H
# array.
# This was performed incorrectly, the published algorithm shows that the eigenvectors 
# are multiplied by the flattened image then scaled by eigenvalues
Igray = np.dot(eigvecs.T, np.dot(eigvals, Izycc)).sum(0).reshape(Iycc.shape[:2])
Igray2 = np.dot(eigvals, np.dot(eigvecs, Izycc)).sum(0).reshape(Iycc.shape[:2])
eigvals3 = eigvals*[1,-1,1]
Igray3 = np.dot(eigvals3, np.dot(eigvecs, Izycc)).sum(0).reshape(Iycc.shape[:2])
eigvals4 = eigvals*[1,-1,-1]
Igray4 = np.dot(eigvals4, np.dot(eigvecs, Izycc)).sum(0).reshape(Iycc.shape[:2])

# Rescale Igray to [0, 255]. This is a fancy way to do this.
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
Igray = np.floor((interp1d([Igray.min(), Igray.max()],
                            [0.0, 256.0 - 1e-4]))(Igray))
Igray2 = np.floor((interp1d([Igray2.min(), Igray2.max()],
                            [0.0, 256.0 - 1e-4]))(Igray2))
Igray3 = np.floor((interp1d([Igray3.min(), Igray3.max()],
                            [0.0, 256.0 - 1e-4]))(Igray3))
Igray4 = np.floor((interp1d([Igray4.min(), Igray4.max()],
                            [0.0, 256.0 - 1e-4]))(Igray4))

# Make sure we don't accidentally produce a photographic negative (flip image
# intensities). N.B.: `norm` is often expensive; in real life, try to see if
# there's a more efficient way to do this.
if norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - Igray) > norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - (255.0 - Igray)):
    Igray = 255 - Igray
if norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - Igray2) > norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - (255.0 - Igray2)):
    Igray2 = 255 - Igray2
if norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - Igray3) > norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - (255.0 - Igray3)):
    Igray3 = 255 - Igray3
if norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - Igray4) > norm(Iycc[:,:,0] - (255.0 - Igray4)):
    Igray4 = 255 - Igray4

# Display result
if True:
    import pylab
    pylab.ion()
fGray =    pylab.imshow(Igray, cmap='gray')
# Save result
cv2.imwrite('peppers-gray.png', Igray.astype(np.uint8))

fGray2 = pylab.imshow(Igray2, cmap='gray')
# Save result
cv2.imwrite('peppers-gray2.png', Igray2.astype(np.uint8))

fGray3 =pylab.imshow(Igray3, cmap='gray')
# Save result
cv2.imwrite('peppers-gray3.png', Igray3.astype(np.uint8))

fGray4 =pylab.imshow(Igray4, cmap='gray')
# Save result
cv2.imwrite('peppers-gray4.png', Igray4.astype(np.uint8))
```

****EDIT*****

Following Nazlok's query about the instability of eigenvector direction (which direction any one eigenvectors is oriented in is arbitrary, so there is not guarantee that different algorithms (or single algorithms without a reproducible standardisation step for orientation) would give the same result. I have now added in two extra examples, where I have simply switched the sign of the eigenvectors (number 2 and numbers 2 and 3). The results are again different, with the switching of only PC2 giving a much lighter tone, while switching 2 and 3 is similar (not surprising as the exponential scaling relegates the influence of PC3 to very little). I'll leave that last one for people bothered to run the code.

[image: Result is the sign of PC2 is switched]

### Conclusion

Without clear additional steps taken to provide a repeatable and reproducible orientation of PCs this algorithm is unstable and I personally would not be comfortable employing it as is. Nazlok's suggestion of using the balance of positive and negative intensities could provide a rule but would need validated so is out of scope of this answer. Such a rule however would not guarantee a 'best' solution, just a stable one. Eigenvectors are unit vectors, so are balanced in variance (square of intensity). Which side of zero has the largest sum of magnitudes is only telling us which side has individual pixels contributing larger variances which I suspect is generally not very informative.

Comment: This looks very close to the result presented in paper, but don't we need something like `for i, eigvec in enumerate(eigvecs.T):\n    if eigvec.sum() < 0:\n        eigvecs[:, i] *= -1` after `eigvals = np.diag(S**2 / norm(S**2))`?

Comment: Can't think any reason you would, but maybe I'm missing something. What is your thinking there?

Comment: Let's consider an extreme case where the three channels in `Izycc` already have zero correlation. Then `np.diag([1, 1, 1])`, `np.diag([1, -1, 1])`, `np.diag([-1, -1, -1])` are all possible values for `eigvecs`, but the only desired one is `np.diag([1, 1, 1])`. Otherwise, channels with a negative coefficient would be incorrectly flipped. The `Igray = 255 - Igray` fix can only flip `np.diag([-1, -1, -1])` back to `np.diag([1, 1, 1])`, but it cannot handle other cases properly.

Comment: I'd not paid attention to what exactly was been done, just medically fixing code. they are converting the right eigenvectors to re-weighted loadings then summing, not projecting the PCA. you are right, this creates a potential instability without a decision rule to arbitrarily standardise the orientation of the losdings.however since the orientation is arbitrary, I don't think there is any guarantee your rule gives the best result, but should be reproducible. I'd need to play around a bit. It's more of a CV question though.